# Why file upload error codes in php miss number '5'?

Tags: file-upload, php

I am writing a custom error handling / reporting function for PHP file upload and I noticed that the error codes returned are numbered from 0 to 8 except 5.

Is this a typo in the source I am using or is it really this way? If it is so, I am curious why they have skipped number '5'.

Thanks.

**Edit**
In response to `Pekka`, here are the error codes from PHP manual.

```
0 | UPLOAD_ERR_OK         | There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
1 | UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   | Size exceeds upload_max_filesize in php.ini.
2 | UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  | Size exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE specified in HTML form.
3 | UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    | The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
4 | UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    | No file was uploaded.
5 | UPLOAD_ERROR_E        | As explained by @Progman, removed in rev.  81792
6 | UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR | Missing a temporary folder.
7 | UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE | Failed to write file to disk.
8 | UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  | File upload stopped by extension.
```

Comment: `and I noticed that the error codes returned is one of numbers 0 to 8 except 5.` where do you have this from? I know only 4 error codes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't matter as you use the `UPLOAD_ERR_*` constants anyway. But I guess the field 5 was an error which is now handled by a different error case.

**Edit**

The case "5" was an error for empty uploaded files. However this isn't an error so the field/constant got removed. See [changeset 81792 on main/rfc1867.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?r1=79486&r2=81792) and [changeset 88408 on main/rfc1867.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?r1=87820&r2=88408)

Comment: Yes using constants is the way to go as the value may change some day. But, my question is `am I missing a case which may return error code 5?`

Comment: @Majid: no, its not defined (anymore), It might be defined in an earlier version but now the field is not used anymore and is not reused to prevent confusion about two cases getting the same index (and this way cannot be distinguished)